# "Less empty" and similar "double negatives"

Tags: adjectives

In English, we can apply a negative adverb to a negative adjective to end up with a positive-pointing adjectival phrase - "less empty," "not small", "less mistaken", and so on. How would I say this in Japanese? Ah, in context I'm trying to maintain a parallel to an existing quote, so I definitely would like to say something of the form 「～[空]{から}の」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「（　　）[空]{から}の」

Correct me if I am wrong, but your assumption here seems to be that there must be a word to fill in that blank so that the whole phrase would mean "***less empty***".

***If so, the answer is that there is no such word in Japanese***.

The form we use for "***less + adjective with negative meaning***" would be:

> 「より + Adjective w/ Negative Meaning ***in its negative form***」 or
>
> 「より + ***Antonym*** of Adjective w/ Negative Meaning」

These would be 「より空で（は）ない」 and 「よりたくさん[入]{はい}っている」, respectively.  I must also add that with 「空の」, the latter expression would sound considerably more natural than the former.  The former form would sound a little wordy to the majority of the native speakers.

Other examples:

"less mistaken" = 「より[間違]{まちが}っていない」 and 「より[正]{ただ}しい」

"less ugly" = 「より[醜]{みにく}くない」 and 「よりきれいな」

Again, the latter form would be the native speaker's choice in both cases.

Comment: Ah, excellent, thanks! I think the first version is nevertheless what I'm looking for - I'm riffing off of an existing quote involving a 「空の～」, so even if it's less natural it's important that it sound similar.